# Is there a way to use the native Mac input methods when connected via TeamViewer

Tags: linux, mac, remote-access, teamviewer, input

When I connect to a Mac machine via TeamViewer (e.g. from a Linux machine), the keyboard input is being sent directly from my controlling machine.

However, it seems that input methods on Linux such as those for Chinese and Japanese don't work in this way. Can I somehow directly use the input methods on the Mac being controlled?

Comment: TeamViewer is closed source, so that'll be difficult to change. You'd have to tell TeamViewer not to read the keyboard directly, but to allow interception by input methods. But if TeamViewer is not programmed this way, there's nothing you can do. You could try to make input methods that grab the physical keyboard exclusively and pretend to produce Chinese/Japanese keys on a physical keyboard via `uinput`, but that will be quite a bit of programming work.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with any remote setup - any keys that the local machine intercepts to do anything 'special' don't get passed on.
There is no fix [other than may be built into your remote software], except to make your local commands non-standard, so they will be correctly received by the remote system instead.